# How to use different db tables for a Django model based on the datetime provided in the queries?

Tags: django, postgresql

**Problem:** I have a model, say `Location`, which has huge amount of rows and any query for this model takes unreasonable amount of time to complete.

I was thinking of using a new table for this model which will enable my app to store future entries to this new table. Also, when the app queries for old data using `created` column, it compares to a hard-coded datetime value in the model and decides which table to use for the query.

Is it possible to setup a model for such use case?

```
1. Location.objects.create(lat='zzzz', lng='zzzzz')  <-- Uses new table
2. Location.objects.filter(created__date__gte=zz-zz-zzzz)  <-- Uses old table
```

I understand that, for 2nd line of code, I won't get the data stored in the new table.

Comment: You may need to overload the `__init__` method of your model.

Comment: you can keep seperate database lightweight like sqllite3 and keep same table name. you can save mapping somewhere to see which database you should select like `Location.objects.using("db1").filter` and `Location.objects.using("db2").filter` see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/multi-db/)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to define custom Manager which will insert the data at the new database. I've not tested the code but it should be something like this.

```
from django.db import models

class LocationBase(models.Model):
    field = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class ProxyLocationManager(models.Manager):
    def create(self, **data):
        return NewLocation.objects.create(**data)
class Location(LocationBase):
    objects = ProxyLocationManager()

class NewLocation(LocationBase):
    class Meta(LocationBase.Meta):
        db_table = 'location_new'
```